# Flutter: How can i change a variable based on theme mode (Maps)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

im trying to change my flutter-google-maps style based on the theme settings. The dark Map-Style should be displayed when dark mode is activated.
This is my code so far:

```
bool _darkModeEnabled = false;

  void _checkIfDarkModeEnabled() {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    theme.brightness == Brightness.dark
        ? _darkModeEnabled = true
        : _darkModeEnabled = false;
  }


  get mapStyle => _darkModeEnabled  ? 'assets/map_styles/dark.json' : 'assets/map_styles/light.json';
```

This is my GoogleMap Code:

```
body: GoogleMap(
                mapType: _currentMapType,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                compassEnabled: false,
                myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                initialCameraPosition: initialLocation,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
                    String style = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                      .loadString(mapStyle);
                  controller.setMapStyle(style);
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                  newGoogleMapController = controller;

                  locatePosition();
                },
              ),
```

This is my themes.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

CustomTheme currentTheme = CustomTheme();

class CustomTheme with ChangeNotifier {
  static bool _isDarkTheme = false;
  ThemeMode get currentTheme => _isDarkTheme ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;

  void toggleTheme() {
    _isDarkTheme = !_isDarkTheme;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  static ThemeData get lightTheme {
    return ThemeData(

        //Color Theme
        brightness: Brightness.light,
...
```

Right now it only changes the map style based on the first line. (bool _darkModeEnabled = false;) if i set it to true the map is dark, if its false the map is light.

Any helped would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the theme of your app at compile time you can modify ThemeData. There is an attribute called Brightness which changes a bunch of colors from light to dark if set to Brightness.dark.